# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority while authenticating to local GitLab instance

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I have an internal hosted GitLab instance, and I am trying to provision resources using Terraform on it.

However, it throws me following error:

```
**Error: Get "https://admin-repo.[ORG DOMAIN].com/api/v4/user": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

terraform {
  required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source  = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "3.7.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "gitlab" {
  token    = var.token
  base_url = var.base_url
}

#token    = "******"
#base_url = "https://admin-repo.[ORG DOMAIN].com"
```

I understand it's a certificate missing issue as cant access the url using browser also as it gives `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

My question is how can get this certificate and configure terraform to use this to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is that you have a self-signed certificate instead of one from a recognized CA.

If you don't want to spend money on your certificate, possibly the easiest way would be to acquire one from Let's Encrypt using `certbot`. Afterwards you can provide that certificate to Terraform without any problem.

The instructions for `certbot` are perfectly explained on their own web depending on your machine and deployed application:

https://certbot.eff.org/instructions

Comment: But how can i instruct terraform to use a particular certificate?

Comment: Terraform doesn't need a particular certificate. Let's Encrypt is already a trusted CA so as soon as you have a certificate issued by them, it will recognize the certificate as issued by a valid issuer and it won't complain. It would be different if you want to use a self-signed certificate. Check here for self-signed certs: https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046090994-Terraform-runs-failing-with-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error